# update panel full post back

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, vb.net-2010, autopostback

i have the below code:

```
    <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="GridView1" OnRowDataBound="gvChildGrid_RowDataBound"  Width="1000px" 
    DataKeyNames="number"   AllowSorting="false" style="font-size:15px;"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#E7E7FF" AllowPaging="true" HorizontalAlign="Center"
    CellPadding="4" GridLines="none">
    <%-- <PagerSettings Mode="NumericFirstLast" FirstPageText="first" PreviousPageText="previous" LastPageText="last" NextPageText="next" Position="bottom" PageButtonCount="2" />--%>
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#F7F7F7" />
    <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText = "Select">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <a href="JavaScript:divexpandcollapse('div<%# Eval("number") %>');">
    <img id="imgdiv" width = "20px" src="images/Alarm-Plus-icon.png" alt="" />
    </a>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True"/>
    </asp:TemplateField>  

    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText = "Number">
    <ItemTemplate>   
    <%# Eval("number")%>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>


    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText = "Name">
    <ItemTemplate>   
    <%# Eval("name")%>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>


    <asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="100%">
    <div id="div<%# Eval("number") %>" style="display: none; position: relative;  overflow: auto">
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:GridView ID="gvChildGrid" DataKeyNames="number" runat="server" BackColor="Transparent" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnPageIndexChanging="gvChildGrid_PageIndexChanging"
    style="Width:100% !important;"  GridLines="None"  Font-Names="times new roman" AllowPaging="True" CellPadding="4"  AllowSorting="True">
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#8cc63e" Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="White" />
        <Columns>                  
        <asp:BoundField DataField="number"  HeaderText="Mobile Number" >
        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="name"  HeaderText="Name" >
        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"  />
        </asp:BoundField>
    </Columns> 
    </asp:GridView>
    </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>

    </Columns>

    </asp:GridView>
```

i'm using an update pannel for the second grid view `gvChildGrid` because i when i use the paging of this gridview i don't want the hole page to post back... only the grid view

but the problem is that the hole page is posting back

how can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Add Update panel to  `<asp:TemplateField>`. It may work I'm not sure.